# How to INSERT INTO SQLite database using Bash?

Tags: bash, scripting, sqlite

I have created a database - tasks.db - with SQLite.
This database has one table - todo - with the following fields :
id (pk), date (NOW with trigger), project, duedate, status, description

To enter a new row in SQLite from the command line, I have to write :

```
sqlite3 tasks.db "insert into todo (project,duedate,status,description) values (2010-11_18,'Home','Urgent','Call the plumber');"
```

which is a rather long and error-prone process. So I decided to "automate" it with a shell script (bsq) which runs as follows :

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "What project ?"
read Proj
echo "For when ?"
read Due
echo "What status ?"
read Stat
echo "What to do ?"
read Descr

echo sqlite3 tasks.db "insert into todo (project,duedate,status,description) values ('$Proj',$Due,'$Stat','$Descr');"
```

… and nothing happens when I run : `sh bsq`. The sequence appears then brings me back to the prompt.

Where did I go wrong or what did I omit (ENTER ? but how do I do that ?)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you expect? You call `echo sqlite ...` it won't invoke sqlite. Please format the source properly. Use the icons above the textarea.

Comment: Is the last echo correct? Or are you executing sqlite3 directly? It works fine here; echoing the command at the end.

Comment: Also: In sh '$Proj' is not treated as a variable. Use `"$Proj"`

Comment: @khachik; incorrect.. the single quotes are within double quotes, so they have no meaning and will be used as is.

Comment: @roe: agreed. I didn't see the double quotes.

Comment: @roe : As you have guessed I am a beginner (which explains why I did not format the source properly). What I wanted to do was - in a single script - to 1) open sqlite3 2) open tasks.db 3) insert a properly formatted row into it 4) come back to the command line.

Comment: Your question is tagged `[bash]`, but your shebang is `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "What project ?"
read Proj
echo "For when ?"
read Due
echo "What status ?"
read Stat
echo "What to do ?"
read Descr

echo "im gonna run" sqlite3 tasks.db "insert into todo \
     (project,duedate,status,description) \
     values (\"$Proj\",$Due,\"$Stat\",\"$Descr\");"
sqlite3 tasks.db "insert into todo (project,duedate,status,description) \
         values (\"$Proj\",$Due,\"$Stat\",\"$Descr\");"
```

Comment: it worked perfectly, of course. Thanks a lot (and this time, I did not forget to ACCEPT the answer...)

Comment: please note: this does not take care of escaping

Comment: What do I have to do to handle escaping?

Comment: To handle escaping don't use sqlite. That is the best answer I found so far within few posts.